Paragraph with entity browser ajax to wrong URL
I have a drupal node that references a paragraph type. Within that paragraph is a series of fields. One of which field is accessing a "view". So the field looks more like this:

As you can see it's an autocomplete.  When I access that node that has the paragraph, it works fine. However if it's nested inside another node, the autocomplete doesn't work.  In fact I looked at the browser's DEVTOOL and looked at network and it spits out the correct URL to get the results but it has extra querystrings that makes it fail.  For example:
I want the field's autocomplete to access the view via site.com/entity_reference_autocomplete/node/views/stuff?type=x
but instead the issue is that it appends this:site.com/entity_reference_autocomplete/node/views/stuff?entity_type=paragraph&entity_id=123?type=x
Is there a hook that can tap into this and remove the other query string?
